# Convert currency to USD using specific value date

Tags: google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet:

```
| date      | amount | currency | USD value |
|-----------|--------|----------|-----------|
|12/31/2017 | 100    | EUR      | formula   |
```

`formula` is:

```
=B1*GoogleFinance(CONCATENATE("CURRENCY:"; C1; "USD");"close";DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);DAY(A1)))
```

It should take `amount` and convert it from `currency` to `USD` using the value date of `date`.

The problem is that I get:

> **Error**
>   Parameter 2 of function MULTIPLY expects numeric values, but "Date" is of type text and cannot be interpreted as number.

What am I doing wrong?

**Notes**:

- I'm using `;` as separator because my locale uses `,` as decimals separator.

Comment: We need sample sheet to make sure you have actual date, not text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("USD"&C1, "close", A1),2,2)*B1
```

Comment: This trick fixed my problem but now half the cells return a #REF error (intermittently on each refresh)...

Comment: Share an example and I will be glad to look at it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/156iMTD5ikMw2x-yDXufQlMp1YpninXcdJlp5vjIPBt4/edit